# how can I access a Key value from ResourceDictionary in wpf using mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have created Resource.fr-CA.xaml, Resource.en-US.xaml files under a Resource folder in my WPF-MVVM application.

I have created Resource.fr-CA.xaml and Resource.en-US.xaml files as follows:

**Resource.fr-CA.xaml**

```
<system:String x:Key="EntUser_PhoneNo_Label">Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone</system:String>
```

**Resource.en-US.xaml**

```
<system:String x:Key="EntUser_PhoneNo_Label">Phone Number</system:String>
```

My app contains one combo-box to select different type of languages.

If user selects **french language** then I have to get value of  **"EntUser_PhoneNo_Label"** key value from **Reource.fr-CA** or if user selects **English** language then I have to get value from **Resource.en-US.xaml**.

Please let me know the solution to how to get key/value from corresponding .xaml file's ResourceDictionary from code behind.

Comment: Hi all , i am able to access key value as follows:

            ResourceDictionary MyResDict = new ResourceDictionary();
            MyResDict.Source = new Uri("/MyLang;component/Resources/Resource.fr-CA.xaml",  UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);           

            byte[] utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( Convert.ToString(MyResDict["LoginButton_Label"]));
            string str1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8String);
            EntUser_PhoneNo_Label = str1;

           but here my problem is I am ubale to convert  "Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone" to "Numéro de téléphone"

Answer (score 0):

This code worked well:

```
   byte[] utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone"); 
   string str1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8String);
```

and this too :

```
public static class  StringDecoder
    {
        public static string Decode(string str)
        {
            if (str == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str, Encoding.UTF8);
        }

    }
var str = StringDecoder.Decode("Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone"); // returns Numéro de téléphone
```